# Returning objects in php?

Tags: php, object

Will returning an object in php make a new instance of that object?

I have a class that stores objects for me in that class is a method that returns any given object. Example;

```
class Simple {

     private $obj = array();

public function loadObj($name) {

    $this->obj[$name] = new $name();
}

public function getObj($key) {

    if(isset($this->obj[$key])) {
        return $this->obj[$key];
    }
}
}
```

Then in my code I can do things like this,

```
$a = new Simple();
$a->addObj('cat');
$cat1 = $a->getObj('cat');
$cat2 = $a->getObj('cat');
```

Does this instantiate a new cat everytime?

Say cat had a variable of color and methods of `setColor` and `getColor`, if I changed the color with `$cat1` and fetched it with `$cat2` would they be the same?

I would test it but I am not at home.

Comment: `addObj` doesn't exist.

Comment: Ye you get the jist...

Answer (score 1):

No, both times only the same value will be returned because you are calling the function on only one object  `$a->` two times. Unless you call your `addObj` multiple times, it wont generate more objects in there. Also `addObj` is not defined in your class. It is `loadObj`

Comment: So if I changed a value using `$cat1` and retrieved it using `$cat2` they would both be changed? Say if the object `cat` had a length value with methods of `getLength` and `setLength`?

Comment: You will have to first write a change value method, only then we can tell if it does that or no

Answer (score 0):

I get what you're asking and I think I found the correct answer in the PHP manual.

"A PHP reference is an alias, which allows two different variables to write to the same value. As of PHP 5, an object variable doesn't contain the object itself as value anymore. It only contains an object identifier which allows object accessors to find the actual object. When an object is sent by argument, returned or assigned to another variable, the different variables are not aliases: they hold a copy of the identifier, which points to the same object."

So yes if you called set color on $cat1 it would also change the color on $cat2 because the references are aliases pointing to the same object.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Answer (score 0):

Each PHP object is [identified by a handle](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) (which is a number). The handle is used by the interpreter to find the object in an internal table.

A variable that stores a PHP object actually stores this handle. When the object is assigned to another variable, the handle is copied to the new variable, not the actual object's data.

> Will returning an object in php make a new instance of that object?

There are two operators that create new objects in PHP: [`new`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new) and [`clone`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php).

All the other manipulations of objects (assignments, objects passed as arguments to functions and objects returned by functions) copy object handles and do not duplicate the actual objects.